# Spring AOP advice not applied to a concrete class if pointcut specified on interface and hierarchy deeper than one level

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

So I have class C implements interface B and interface B extends interface A.

My aop-config.xml:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
  </tx:advice>

  <aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="aMethods" expression="execution(* com.mypackage.A.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="aMethods"/>
  </aop:config>
```

Basically I want for all classes implementing interface A their methods to run in transactional context.

It doesn't seem to work when the pointcut expression is pointing to interface A but it does work if pointing to interface B.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a pointcut for an exact match for type `A` **NOT** for subtypes. To include subtypes add a + to the pointcut.

```
<aop:pointcut id="aMethods" expression="execution(* com.mypackage.A+.*(..))"/>
```

For more information [the AspectJ reference guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#type-patterns). [AspectJ in Action 2nd](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/) is also a book I can recommend.